# Not able to change the value of the char variable

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    char c;
    int i;
    clrscr();
    scanf("%c",&c);
    scanf("%c",&c);
    printf("%c",c);
    getch();
}
```

This program does not takes the value of the char c for the second time however it works fine in the case of the integer variable. Why so?

Comment: Yes, it does. You just don't notice *which* char value it takes. :)

Comment: The `%c` field descriptor is different to `scanf()` than most others in that it does not skip leading whitespace.  This is precisely so that it can scan *any* character, including whitespace characters.  Of all the standard `scanf()` conversion specifiers, only `c`, `[`, and `n` have this property (and `n` is a special case).

Answer (score 1):

Add in an extra space before `%c`:

```
 scanf(" %c",&c);
```

This is because in the previous `scanf`, you entered the character, and then a newline `\n`. Thus, in the first `scanf`, the character was stored, and in the second `scanf` the newline was stored.

Alternatively, you can use `getchar` to store the newline. Add `getchar()` before the second `scanf` and after the first `scanf`.

Comment: understood your point but the same does not happen in case of the integer variable..why this happens in case of the char only??

Comment: @AnkitBatra: because `%d` automatically skips the whitespace and newline, whereas `%c` can't: it takes them as actual characters. (In your program `\n` does get printed).

Answer (score 1):

It's because when you enter the first character, you probably end it with a newline, and that newline is still in the input buffer so the next `scanf` call will read that newline. So when you print it, it prints a newline.

You can tell `scanf` to discard leading whitespace by adding a single space before the format: `" %c"`.

Comment: understood your point but the same does not happen in case of the integer variable..why this happens in case of the char only??

Comment: @AnkitBatra Because just about any other format have it built in to skip leading whitespace. See e.g. [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: also if i am using fflush between the 2 scanf then why it doesn't work as the newline should be thrown over by fflush:-
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
char c;
int i;
clrscr();
scanf("%c",&c);
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%c",&c);
printf("%c",c);
getch();
}

Comment: @AnkitBatra First of all you're flushing the standard *output*. Secondly, calling `fflush` on an input `FILE*` (like `stdin`)  is *undefined behavior*. Some libraries might implement some semantics for it, but you should in generally avoid it. If you portably want to skip until a newline, call e.g. `fgetc` in a loop.